# Python requests: Getting the size (in bytes) of requested file (mp4)

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm currently trying to download a video using Python Requests, and I want to find out the size of it first.

```
import requests

print("STARTING PROGRAM...")

req = requests.get("https://www.source.com/source.mp4")
```

The only way I thought of is the following:

```
for chunk in req.iter_content():
  count+=1
print("FOUND %d CHUNKS" %(count))
```

But that took quite a long time since I am downloading a 24-min mp4. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: _But that took quite a long time since I am downloading a 24-min mp4._ You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests useful.

Comment: @AMC Not the real problem I want to solve here, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @Cyh1368 I'm curious, what is the real problem? The answers to this question are still appropriate though, right?

Comment: @AMD The problem here is to find a way to get the size of request, though fastening the process can indirectly help too.

Comment: @danill I never really think that much, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the head of the file, to get the file size without downloading:

```
import requests
response = requests.head("https://www.source.com/source.mp4")
print(response.headers)
```

You should then get something called `content-length` which is what you want.

Or alternatively, just print the size:

```
print(response.headers['content-length'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send a HEAD request.

```
import requests

response = requests.head('https://www.source.com/source.mp4')
size = response.headers['content-length']
```

This will return the size in bytes.

Comment: Some websites don't set this value. You can see this when your browser just does a loop instead of a proper progress bar. Beware you can't 100% trust headers.

Comment: I don't see how this is better than my answer considering I posted before you...